# FacebookSDK Corekit framework error

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to use the FacebookSDK Sharekit/Corekit framework for including posting feature in my app. I dragged and dropped `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` and `FBSKShareKit.framework` in to Xcode project.

When I build the app it gave me error in 3 of the following FBSDKCoreKit.framework header file:

1. FBSDKProfile.h
2. FBSDKGraphRequest.h
3. FBSDKAccessToken.h

Here is an image of the error

[image]

Here is the code that gives this error.

```
- (instancetype)initWithTokenString:(NSString *)tokenString
                        permissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                declinedPermissions:(NSArray *)declinedPermissions
                              appID:(NSString *)appID
                             userID:(NSString *)userID
                     expirationDate:(NSDate *)expirationDate
                        refreshDate:(NSDate *)refreshDate NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

It says `Lexical or Preprocessor  Issue Expected ‘:’`

Not sure why would a framework file give error. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Did you download it from developers.facebook.com or built it yourself after cloning the Git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything, the solution was to upgrade to Xcode 7 from Xcode 5.